# How do I Server My WebApp files with Couchdb

Tags: webserver, couchdb

I would like to develop an application with CouchDB, I believe that is possible to use ONLY CouchCB to server *html, css, fonts, icons, js, etc.* files as well as to store the data and handle them.

The problems I am facing is:

> How to serve my files using CouchDB (without having to use any middleware like nodejs), what I found is that I can upload them as attachements to a **_design** document, but I find it not a practical way to do so for every single file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for couchapps. There are tools that take care of the uploading part for you like [erica](https://github.com/benoitc/erica) and [couchapp](https://github.com/couchapp/couchapp).

Couchapp documentation is in the [wiki part](https://github.com/couchapp/couchapp/wiki) of the repo. Here is the [file structure](https://github.com/couchapp/couchapp/wiki/Complete-Filesystem-to-Design-Doc-Mapping-Example) to design doc mapping guide.

For erica everything is in the readme.

Comment: Okay, I will have a look on that, do you know any getting started link to couchapp, or erica? the main website for couchapp seems to be down

Comment: I have provided more links in the answer. Let me know if it helps.